# How to make the function wait till I get the response in node.js

Tags: node.js, callback, async-await

Async and Await are not working as expected. Please correct me where I am doing wrong in code.
I am reading data (url, pagelimit, company)from excel and by using switch(), I am navigating to the service. 
I have to wait till I get the response from this function cnbservice.GetcnbOpenings(url, pageLimit,company), store the response to global array and call this function mdsservice.GetMdsOpenings(url, pageLimit,company), append the results to the global array.

```
    const readexcel = async (request, response) => {

    const workbook = XLSX.readFile('file.xlsx');
    const sheetnamelist = workbook.SheetNames;
    var xldata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetnamelist[0]]);
    dataarray =[];
    for (i = 0; i < xldata.length; i++) {
        company = xldata[i].company;
        url = xldata[i].careers_link_url;
        pageLimit = xldata[i].pagelimit;       

        switch(company){
        case process.env.cnb_company_name:        
          const arr = await cnbservice.GetcnbOpenings(url, pageLimit,company)
          if(arr !== undefined){
            dataarray.push(arr);
        }
            break;
        case process.env.mds_company_name:
        const arr1 = await mdsservice.GetMdsOpenings(url, pageLimit,company)    
        if(arr1 !== undefined){    
        dataarray.push(arr1);
    }
            break;
        case "default":
            console.log("Company Name not matching with any of the services")
            }


    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running await code inside standard for loop which will not work synchronously. to run async/await inside a for loop you should use `for...of` loop.

```
 for(let element of array){
  //await call
  }
```

after making following changes your code will work as expected.

```
const readexcel = async (request, response) => {

    const workbook = XLSX.readFile('file.xlsx');
    const sheetnamelist = workbook.SheetNames;
    var xldata = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheetnamelist[0]]);
    dataarray = [];
    for (let element of xldata) {
        company = element.company;
        url = element.careers_link_url;
        pageLimit = element.pagelimit;

        switch (company) {
            case process.env.cnb_company_name:
                const arr = await cnbservice.GetcnbOpenings(url, pageLimit, company)
                if (arr !== undefined) {
                    dataarray.push(arr);
                }
                break;
            case process.env.mds_company_name:
                const arr1 = await mdsservice.GetMdsOpenings(url, pageLimit, company)
                if (arr1 !== undefined) {
                    dataarray.push(arr1);
                }
                break;
            case "default":
                console.log("Company Name not matching with any of the services")
        }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Yogesh for the quick response. Even after making your changes to code. Basically, what is happening is - The cnbservice.GetcnbOpenings(url, pageLimit,company) has to scrape data from 7 pages and mdsservice.GetMdsOpenings(url, pageLimit,company) has to scrape 11 pages. My agenda is to make the first function read all the 7 pages and execute the second function which will read 11 pages data. Currently it is reading the 1 page of the first function and 1st page of the second function alternatively.